# Python Selenium- not able to disable third party cookies blocking

Tags: python, selenium

Whenever I login into the website, the page is blocked from loading all the content, it is due to the third party cookie blocking.

In order to access all the data on the page, I have to allow cookies every time I login. I even have allowed all cookies in chrome settings.

I have used driver.get_cookie() but still not able to proceed.

Please help

Code:

```
driver.maximize_window() 

driver.get('website')

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.title_contains("Sign in to your account"))

username_input = '//*[@id="116"]'

next_button = '//*[@id="idon9"]'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_input).send_keys("abc@gmail.com")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

keep_me_signed_in = '//*[@id="kinput"]'

password_input = '//*[@id="paoinput"]'

sign_in_button = '//*[@id="subon"]'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_input).send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(sign_in_button).click()

dont_show_this_again = '//*[@id="checkfield"]'

yes_button = '//*[@id="on9"]'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(dont_show_this_again).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(yes_button).click()

cook = driver.get_cookie()
    
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

Comment: You can try to use the next approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348230/8951897

Comment: Greate simple solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007362/8951897