# get cookies for www subdomain, or a particular domain?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm calling `get_cookies()` on my selenium web driver. Of course we know this fetches the cookies for the current domain. However, many popular sites set cookies on both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Technically, it's not really a "separate domain" or even sub domain. I think nearly every website on the internet has the same site at the www sub domain as it does the root.

So is it still impossible to save cookies for the two domains, since one is a sub domain? I know the answer is complicated if you want to save cookies for all domains, but I figured this is kind of different since they really are the same domain.

Replicate it with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

print(driver.get_cookies())
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'ig_did', 'value': 'F5FDFBB0-7D13-4E4E-A100-C627BD1998B7', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.instagram.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True, 'expiry': 1671083433}, {'name': 'mid', 'value': 'X9hOqQAEAAFWnsZg8-PeYdGqVcTU', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.instagram.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1671083433}, {'name': 'ig_nrcb', 'value': '1', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.instagram.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1639547433}, {'name': 'csrftoken', 'value': 'Yy8Bew6500BinlUcAK232m7xPnhOuN4Q', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.instagram.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1639461034}]
```

Then load the page in a fresh browser instance and check yourself. You'll see www is there.

[image]

The main domain looks fine though:

[image]

Comment: Tried instagram on Firefox, it does not have `www.instagram.com` cookies. Only Chrome does. Plus, if you want to get cookies of other sites instead of current site, it's not really possible. You will need to use Chrome & parse the encrypted cookies in SQLite file.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use requests library and get all cookies via REST query?

```
    import requests 
  
# Making a get request 
response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/') 
  
# printing request cookies 
print(response.cookies)
```

Comment: what about javascript rendering?

Answer (score 0):

### Domain

To host your application on the internet need a domain name. Domain names act as a placeholder for the complex string of numbers known as an IP address. As an example,

```
https://www.instagram.com/
```

With the latest [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *v84.0* accessing the [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) application the following cookies are observed within the `https://www.instagram.com` domain:

[image: instagram_firefox]

---

### Subdomain

A [subdomain](https://www.hostgator.com/blog/subdomain-vs-domain/#:%7E:text=Essentially%2C%20a%20subdomain%20is%20a,blog.bestwebdesigner.com.%E2%80%9D) is an add-on to your primary domain name. For example, when using the sites e.g. Craigslist, you are always using a subdomain like `reno.craigslist.org`, or `sfbay.craigslist.org`. You will be automatically be forwarded to the subdomain that corresponds to your physical location. Essentially, a subdomain is a separate part of your website that operates under the same primary domain name.

---

### Reusing cookies

If you have stored the cookie from domain `example.com`, these stored cookies **can't** be pushed through the webdriver session to any other different domanin e.g. `example.edu`. The stored cookies can be used only within `example.com`. Further, to automatically login an user in future, you need to store the cookies only once, and that's when the user have logged in. Before adding back the cookies you need to browse to the same domain from where the cookies were collected.

---

### Demonstration

As an example, you can store the cookies once the user have logged in within an application as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php')
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("abc123")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123xyz")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

# storing the cookies
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
driver.quit()
```

Later at any point of time if you want the user automatically logged-in, you need to browse to the specific domain /url first and then you have to add the cookies as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php')

# loading the stored cookies
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    # adding the cookies to the session through webdriver instance
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_cookie.php')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: Document is cookie-averse using Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352380/org-openqa-selenium-invalidcookiedomainexception-document-is-cookie-averse-usin/48353851#48353851)