# Facebook does not allows to login loading the stored cookies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cookies, pickle

I have logged in to Facebook using selenium and saved cookies in a .pkl file
but next time when I load cookies and refresh page, it won't log me in

Here is my code for login step:

```
import pickle
driver.get('https://facebook.com/')
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(f"cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

Load login info step:

```
cookies = pickle.load(open(f"cookies/{username}.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
```

And still I'm not logged in.
Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 0):

To login within [*Facebook*](https://www.facebook.com/) using [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65330984/7429447) you need to follow a couple of steps as follows:

- You should collect the [**cookies**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59957467/7429447) only after first time you have successfully logged in.
- Moving ahead if you add the [*cookies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59843387/7429447) and access the *url* you will be automatically logged in.
- Sample codeblock:

  ```
  driver.get('https://facebook.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email"))).send_keys(email)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#pass"))).send_keys(password +Keys.RETURN)
  pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(),open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Account Controls and Settings'] svg[aria-label='Your profile']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Log Out')]"))).click()
  cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
  for cookie in cookies:
      driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  driver.get('https://facebook.com/')
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'cookie' while adding cookies using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008126/7429447)
- [How to avoid Instagram login page everytime using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137917/7429447)

Comment: Have you ever tried this way? Cause it's not working for me...