# How to continue request session with cookies in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, session, cookies, python-requests

Is it possible to continue a request session in selenium will all its cookies, i have seen many people doing it the other way arround but i have no clue how to do it proper the way i want.

```
    def open_selenium_session(self):
        # get or set cookies 
        driver = get_chromedriver(self.proxy, use_proxy=True, user_agent=True)
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        for cookie in cookies:
            self.session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you have stored the cookies previesly from an active session using `pickle`:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

You can always set them back as follows:

```
# loading the stored cookies
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    # adding the cookies to the session through webdriver instance
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: Document is cookie-averse using Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352380/org-openqa-selenium-invalidcookiedomainexception-document-is-cookie-averse-usin/48353851#48353851)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain while executing tests in Django with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877561/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidcookiedomainexception-message-invalid-cookie/59878718#59878718)