# Unable to load cookie in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to load a cookie saved with selenium WebDriver in order to automatically login into GitHub account. Any ideas what i am doing wrong? This is the script output: selenium.common.exceptions.UnableToSetCookieException: Message: unable to set cookie

```
chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login_field']").send_keys("*********")
chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']").send_keys("***********")
chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login']/div[4]/form/div/input[12]").click()
time.sleep(3)
save_cookies(chrome,"saved_cookies.txt")
chrome.quit

time.sleep(2)
chrome1 = webdriver.Chrome()
load_cookies(chrome,"saved_cookies.txt")
chrome1.get("https://github.com")
```

These are the functions I use:

```
def save_cookies(driver, location):
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(location, "wb"))

def load_cookies(driver, location, url=None):
    cookies = pickle.load(open(location, "rb"))
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    url = "https://github.com" if url is None else url
    driver.get(url)
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me. However one possible improvement would be while saving the cookies using *`pickle.dump()`* instead of a *text* file ideally you should be using ***`.pkl`*** file. As an example, *`saved_cookies.pkl`*.

Your effective line of code will be:

```
save_cookies(chrome,"saved_cookies.pkl")
```

and

```
load_cookies(chrome,"saved_cookies.pkl")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: Document is cookie-averse using Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353851/7429447)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solved the problem. I have some feeling that there are some incompatibilities between Python and Selenium versions. These are the versions I use: Name: selenium
Version: 4.1.3
Python 3.10.4